# Development tools for SharePoint

Tags: asp.net, .net, sharepoint

I am from an asp.net background and I am using the Visual Studio & TFS to build the web applications. Now I want to start a new SharePoint project, so what are the required development tools if I need to write some code to extend SharePoint or develop web parts? Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in addition to answer of [Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1812512/sean):

You can download add on for visual studio "CKSDev" which is very useful tool in the development process. This will allow you to publish DLLs and resources without compiling and installing package every time you do a change in the code or/and aspx/ascx files.

If not standard templates of VS are all you need to start development.

Here is some tools list useful when develop under SharePoint:

1. **RR CAML Query Helper** - helps to build CAML queries
2. **SharePoint List Item Editing Tool** - helps to edit items in the list (advanced usage)
3. **ULS Deobfuscator** - helps to view logs
4. **ULS Viewer** - helps to view logs
5. **Sharepoint Manager 2010** - Helps to explore your farm and all information of SharePoint (Very useful)
6. **SPFeature Explorer** - explores installed fetures on the Farm
7. **Chris O Brien SP Deployment Wizard** - Hekps to export, import entire sites or specifique resources.
8. **Managed Metadata Exporter** - if you work with MMS service application this will be useful to export data to make it available on the other MMS or to create backup.

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 both come with built-in project templates for SharePoint development and it's all written in .Net so as far as your IDE goes that's all you really need.

You will however need the SharePoint DLLs which you could copy across from a SharePoint server, or you can install SharePoint locally. For instructions on how to do this on windows 7, see this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnwpowell/archive/2009/11/24/how-to-install-sharepoint-2010-on-windows-7.aspx (this article also links on to the full MSDN post, which contains all the instructions in detail if you're stuck)